# Referencia de objetos nula en un RecyclerView apuntando a un paquete

Tags: java, android-studio, retrofit

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación del tiempo y el diseño es con tres tabs, el problema me viene al mostrar las predicciones para los próximos cinco días en un `recycler`, el cual genera un error indicándome que invoco una referencia de objetos nula. He usado el depurador y efectivamente, los valores son nulos, pero no consigo dar con el error.

**Mi adapter**:

```
public class MyCincoDiasRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCincoDiasRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<Day> mValues;
    //El error era que estaba declarado como final y no como private solo
    private IPredictionListener mListener;
    //Recordar que hay que poner el context, como en los ejemplos de Miguel
    Context ctx;

    public MyCincoDiasRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Day> items, IPredictionListener listener, Context context ) {
        mValues = items;
        ctx = context;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_cincodias_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        Day currentDay = mValues.get(position);

        List<Predictions> mainPredictionList = currentDay.getMainPredictionList();

        //Para mostrar la fecha del día
        holder.fechaActual.setText(currentDay.getLongFormatDate(ctx));

        //Declaramos el objeto para poder obtener las predicciones
        Predictions prediccionActual = mainPredictionList.get(0);
        holder.iconoEstadoDia.setImageResource(prediccionActual.getWeather().get(0).getCustomIcons());
        //holder.tmpMaxima.setText(prediccionActual.getMain().getTempMax());
       holder.tmpMaxima.setText(prediccionActual.getMain().getTempMax().toString());
        holder.tmpMaxima.setText(prediccionActual.getMain().getTempMin().toString());

        //holder.diaSemana.setText(prediccionActual.getName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public Day mItem;

        /*Intentaremos mostrar por cada día el pronóstico más actual*/
        @BindView(R.id.textView_fecha_actual)
        TextView fechaActual;

        @BindView(R.id.id_dia_semana)
        TextView diaSemana;

        //cambiar esto por la hora en caso de que no salga
        @BindView(R.id.estado_dia)
        TextView estadoDia;

        @BindView(R.id.textView_temperatura_maxima)
        TextView tmpMaxima;

        @BindView(R.id.textView_temperatura_minima)
        TextView tmpMinima;

        @BindView(R.id.imageView_estado_dia)
        ImageView iconoEstadoDia;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;

            /*
            Para simplificar las cosas usamos ButterKnife
             */
            ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + /*mContentView.getText()*/  "'";
        }
    }
}
```

**El fragment**:

```
public class CincoDiasFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";

    private int mColumnCount = 1;
    private IPredictionListener mListener;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public CincoDiasFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cincodias_list, container, false);

        // Set the adapter
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }

             /*Además este método filtra las predicciones y se las pasa al adapter*/
            consultarPronostico();

        }
        return view;
    }

    /*Consultando el pronóstico para poder mostrarlo*/
    private void consultarPronostico() {

        /*Una vez más, recurrimos a las preferencias para leer la ciudad, latitud y longitud*/
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String lon = sharedpreferences.getString(Constantes.KEY_CURRENT_LON,"");
        String lat = sharedpreferences.getString(Constantes.KEY_CURRENT_LAT,"");
        String city = sharedpreferences.getString(Constantes.KEY_CURRENT_CITY,"");

        mListener.cambiarTitulo(city);

        /*Consulta retrofit*/
        Retrofit retrofit = ((AutocompleteApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getRetrofitOpenWeather();
        final IOpenWeatherApi service = retrofit.create(IOpenWeatherApi.class);
        //final Call<RootPredictions> call =service.getPronostico(lat,lon);

        final Call<RootPredictions> call = service.getPronostico(lat,lon);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<RootPredictions>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<RootPredictions> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                if (response.isSuccess()){
                    RootPredictions rootDayList = response.body();

                    /*Creando la lista de días*/
                    getListaDias(rootDayList);

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error" + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    /*Obteniendo una lista de días a partir de las predicciones*/
    public void getListaDias(RootPredictions root) {
        //Obteniendo las fechas con el maestro Joda
        DateTime day0 = new DateTime();
        String strDay0 = day0.getDayOfMonth()+" / "+day0.getMonthOfYear();

        DateTime day1 = day0.plusDays(1);
        String strDay1 = day1.getDayOfMonth()+" / "+day1.getMonthOfYear();

        DateTime day2 = day0.plusDays(2);
        String strDay2 = day2.getDayOfMonth()+" / "+day2.getMonthOfYear();

        DateTime day3 = day0.plusDays(3);
        String strDay3 = day3.getDayOfMonth()+" / "+day3.getMonthOfYear();

        DateTime day4 = day0.plusDays(4);
        String strDay4 = day4.getDayOfMonth()+" / "+day4.getMonthOfYear();


        /*Fintrando las predicciones*/
        List<Predictions> day0List = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Predictions> day1List = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Predictions> day2List = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Predictions> day3List = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Predictions> day4List = new ArrayList<>();

        /*bucle que sirve para guardar las predicciones, cada predicción en su array correspondiente*/
        for (Predictions p:
            root.getPredictionList()) {
            if (p.getDayMonth().equals(strDay0)){
                day0List.add(p);
            }else if (p.getDayMonth().equals(strDay1)){
                day1List.add(p);
            }else if (p.getDayMonth().equals(strDay2)){
                day2List.add(p);
            }else if (p.getDayMonth().equals(strDay3)){
                day3List.add(p);
            }else if (p.getDayMonth().equals(strDay4)){
                day4List.add(p);
            }
        }

        /*Para obtener la lista de los días, colocamos cada listado en su día con su fecha*/
        List<Day> dayList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (day0List.size()>0){
            dayList.add(new Day(day0List.get(0).getDt(),day0List));
        }
        if (day1List.size()>0){
            dayList.add(new Day(day1List.get(0).getDt(),day1List));
        }

        if (day2List.size()>0){
            dayList.add(new Day(day2List.get(0).getDt(),day2List));
        }

        if (day3List.size()>0){
            dayList.add(new Day(day3List.get(0).getDt(),day3List));
        }
        if (day4List.size()>0){
            dayList.add(new Day(day4List.get(0).getDt(),day4List));
        }


        /*Al final lo mostramos en el recyclerView*/
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyCincoDiasRecyclerViewAdapter(dayList,mListener,getActivity()));


    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof IPredictionListener) {
            mListener = (IPredictionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
       mListener = null;
    }
}
```

**El error**:

> W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented W/OpenGLRenderer:
>   Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe1119220,
>   error=EGL_SUCCESS E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
>   E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout I/Choreographer:
>   Skipped 93 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its
>   main thread. D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.jmpgallego.di_maps, PID: 5275
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)'
>   on a null object reference
>                         at com.example.jmpgallego.di_maps.fragments.CincoDiasFragment.getListaDias(CincoDiasFragment.java:189)
>                         at com.example.jmpgallego.di_maps.fragments.CincoDiasFragment$1.onResponse(CincoDiasFragment.java:108)

**Las líneas 189 y 108 son respectivamente**:

```
 recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyCincoDiasRecyclerViewAdapter(dayList,mListener,getActivity()));

 getListaDias(rootDayList);
```

Comment: Agrega tu layout fragment_cincodias_list.xml para sugerirte el id correcto del RecyclerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es dentro de tu método

```
getListaDias(rootDayList);
```

especificamente en la linea:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyCincoDiasRecyclerViewAdapter(dayList,mListener,getActivity()));
```

`recyclerView` tiene valor null, de hecho estas creando una instancia de `recyclerView` cuando se tiene una variable a nivel de clase para esto.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cincodias_list, container, false);

  // Set the adapter
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view; //????????
            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }

             /*Además este método filtra las predicciones y se las pasa al adapter*/
            consultarPronostico();

        }
```

**Debes bucar dentro del layout `fragment_cincodias_list.xml` el `RecyclerView`**, para crear una instancia (en este ejemplo se supone como id R.id.recyclerview).

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cincodias_list, container, false);

recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview); //Busca el RecyclerView dentro de fragment_cincodias_list.xml

        // Set the adapter
       //if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
        //    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }

             /*Además este método filtra las predicciones y se las pasa al adapter*/
            consultarPronostico();

        }
```

Comment: Correcto esa era la solución! No te doy un abrazo porque no sé donde estás! ahora mismo por lo menos se me muestra la pantalla con las predicciones, aunque si busco otra ciudad se cierra la aplicación, pero bueno ya va uno más motivado a por el siguiente error, muchas gracias! postearé el siguiente error pronto! jajaja